# slim framework 4 fresh installation routes are not working

Tags: php, slim

Fresh installation of version 4 kindly help me out to resolve this issue

```php
<?php

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = AppFactory::create();

$app->get('/hello', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
$response->getBody()->write("Hello world!");
    return $response;
});

$app->run();
```

Comment: What is exactly your issue?

Comment: Have you tried to set the basePath?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Slim\Exception\HttpNotFoundException: Not found. in C:\xampp\htdocs\speakpubapi\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware.p

Comment: yeah  i also tried by adding baspath.its works on  "/" root route but anything "/anyroute" with this is not working

Comment: Do you have configured the single entry point reroute in the .htaccess as well? http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/start/web-servers.html